# Markov process and non-deterministic random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

How do I show the following:
If $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are non-deterministic random variables and we define the process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ by $X_t = Z_1 \cos(t)+ Z_2 \sin(t)$. I want to show that this is not a Markov process. What could be an intuitive argument for this fact?

Comment: Let $f(t) = a \cos(t) + b \sin(t)$ for some unknown $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. If I tell you $f(t_1)$ for some $t_1 > 0$, can you tell me $f(t_2)$ for $t_2 > t_1$?

Answer (score 1):

If $(X_t)$ is a Markov process we would have for $t>t_1>t_2$ :$$
P(X_t\in A\mid X_{t_1}=x_1,X_{t_2}=x_2) = 
P(X_t\in A\mid X_{t_1}=x_1)
$$ But for example $t=\frac34\pi$, $t_1=\frac12\pi$, $t_2=0$ this is not true right? Now how do I get on from here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but if $\mathcal F_t=\sigma \{X_s\mid s\leq t\}$, then $X_t\in \mathcal F_s$ for all $s\leq t$. In particular 
$$\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid \mathcal F_s\}=\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\}=\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid X_s\},$$
so it looks to be a Markov process.

Comment: How do you propose to get the last equality? $\sigma(X_t) \neq \sigma(X_s)$.

Comment: Because $\boldsymbol 1_{X_t\in A}$ is $\sigma (X_s)$ measurable, no ?

Comment: That would be like saying $\sigma(a Z_1 + b Z_2) = \sigma(c Z_1 + d Z_2)$ for general $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @snar: Yes, isn't it true ?

Comment: $a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, d = 1.$